# IPv6 support mandate for iOS app submission from June 2016

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, ipv6

As per [Apple news](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a), IPv6 support is mandatory for app submission. Is it just applicable for iOS version 9 and above or is it just mandatory for previous version of iOS (such as versions 7 and 8)?

Comment: It indicates that *all* submissions will have to support IPv6 after that date. Just because your app targets an older release doesn't mean that it would be excluded from the rule as the app would also run on iOS9

Comment: I talked to someone at Apple about this. Every app uploaded to the App Store must work on an IPv6-only (at least NAT64/DNS64, preferably end-to-end IPv6) network. IPv4 support is optional ;)